# Batch to find all specific folders

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I have several folders named "temp", and I would find them, but when I run the application, only the first instance is shown. What should be done to show the others?

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\" %%i in (temp) do @if exist "%%i" set path=%%i
echo %path%
pause :: Pause the app.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What should be done to show the others?

You need to perform the `echo` inside the `for` loop and inside the `if` test otherwise you are only `echo`ing the last match.

In addition:

- I would not use `path` as a variable (`PATH` is an already defined environment variable).
- Name your variables `_somename` instead (the leading `_` prevents name clashes with existing environment variables).
- It is a good idea to use `setlocal` to stop your variables leaking to the parent command prompt.
- You need to use `set setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` so that the updated value is `echo`ed each time around the loop.

Try the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\" %%i in (temp) do (
  @if exist "%%i" (
    @set _variable=%%i
    @echo !_variable!
    )
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to list them, rather than visiting them one at a time, use the following commands:

```
cd \
dir temp /a:d /b /s > "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tempdirs.txt"
start "" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tempdirs.txt"
```

To break this down:

1. Go to the root of your drive (this command will only scan one drive at a time).
2. Use the `dir` command to find things named "temp".
3. Require the things have the attribute "directory" (that is, be folders).
4. Display output in "bare" format, just the file (or, in this case, folder) names.
5. Start from the current directory and also check all subdirectories (this is why we ran the command from drive's root).
6. Redirect the output to a file (just to make it easier to read it all later).
7. Place this file in the Desktop folder under your user profile (`%USERPROFILE%` expands to the path to your profile, something like `C:\Users\username`).
8. Open that file you just wrote out in your default .txt editor (usually Notepad).

Example result from running these commands on my machine:

> C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1498554065-3975735064-3637327715-1001\$RBC5Q5G\Temp
>   C:\KDE\Temp
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\production\temp
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\RAC\Temp
>   C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\production\temp
>   C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\RAC\Temp
>   C:\Users\cbhacking\AppData\Local\Temp
>   C:\Users\cbhacking\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\Temp
>   C:\Users\cbhacking\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSOIdentityCRL\production\temp
>   C:\Users\cbhacking\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\SyncSettings\1733649840\Temp
>   C:\Users\cbhacking\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\vshub\Settings\SyncSettings\1206173302\Temp

Comment: Did you actually try to run `dir temp /a:d /b /s`? It produces no output ... without the `/b` it only finds the top level temp and none of the subdirectories called temp ... you need to do a lot more work on this answer before it will work.

Comment: Of course I tested it. Edited with output from the command sequence, directly copy-pasted out of Notepad++ (except to prepend the `>` for quoting). Not sure why it combined a couple lines, but that's me failing at Markdown, not the command doing that; they're separate in the file. Besides, as I expect you know, `/B` just changes the output format, not the search behavior. Win8.1 Enterprise x64, `cmd.exe`, in case any of that matters.

Comment: That's strange it doesn't work here. Win 7 cmd.exe

Comment: http://imgur.com/Md5HnUO

Comment: Bizarre. http://imgur.com/fEkWXk3 (the findstr is to prevent it from including private paths from my user profile). The only significant difference I see, other than the OS version (does Win7 not support the `/S` switch? I know it supports `/A`) is that you're not working from drive `C:`. I just tried it from `D:` and it worked there too, though.

Comment: Yes. It is bizarre. It does support the /s switch. See my output from `dir /a:d /b /s | findstr /e temp`. The `/e` is to force matches of names ending in `temp` to cut down the output. http://imgur.com/xLb9MWj

Comment: I have the same issue on drive `C:`. It will list directories in `c:\temp` but misses other `temp` directories like `c:\users\DavidPostill\temp`

Comment: Part of the mystery is solved, at least for me. if `f:\temp` is empty I get no output. If I `mkdir f:\temp\test` then I get `F:\temp\test` as output from `dir temp /a:d /b /s`. Why it requires a subdirectory to work I've no idea. And it still doesn't find `f:\test\temp` or `f:\test\temp\test`.

Comment: This works in Windows Server 2016 1607 FWIW